# When to start and stop In-App Billing service?

Tags: android, service, in-app-purchase

A simple question, that I however can't resolve: when should I start and stop the billing service? I'm thinking about two decisions:

- starting in onCreate and stopping in onDestroy
- starting in onResume and stopping in onPause

What is the best practice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having your billing service derive from IntentService so that it will be started/stopped automatically when it needs to be. You start it using startService(Intent), and then when it's finished with it's work it will shut itself down. IntentService also provides built in queue so only one intent will be processed at once, and it's own worker thread.

As I recall, you also need a Receiver to use IAB, which could then call the service with an Intent, and have the action set based on what needs to be done.

Comment: The IntentService calls stopSelf when the (last) service onHandleCommand finishes. But at that time the service is not always done. If the service needs to send a message to MarketBilling, it needs to connect the to the MarketBillingService. When it binds to the service, it calls bind(), then it returns from the onHandle, and later the ServiceConnection object receives a onServiceConnection callback. If the Service is dead by this time (which it could be but isn't when I test on Android 3.2) then I would expect things to fail, beceause the context is dead.